# Makeadder example from Ben Alman

Tags: javascript

In the below, where does b come from? I don't see it being passed in, so how could it be returned?

```
function lockInFirstArg( fn, a ) {
  return function( b ) {
    return fn( a, b );
  };
}
```

Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptjunkie/gg575560

More complete excerpt:

```
// More-general functions.
 
function add( a, b ) {
  return a + b;
}
 
function multiply( a, b ) {
  return a * b;
}
 
// Relatively flexible more-specific function generator.
 
function lockInFirstArg( fn, a ) {
  return function( b ) {
    return fn( a, b );
  };
}
 
var add1 = lockInFirstArg( add, 1 );
add1( 2 );    // 3
add1( 3 );    // 4
add1( 10 );   // 11
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at what currying is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

templatetypedef has already provided an explanation, I'll show you little breakdown in code.

Our setup:

```
function add( a, b ) {
  return a + b;
}

function lockInFirstArg( fn, a ) {
  return function( b ) {
    return fn( a, b );
  };
}
```

Now let's look at the following:

```
var add1 = lockInFirstArg( add, 1 );
```

And break it down:

```
// passes in the function object and 1 as arguments
var add1 = lockInFirstArg(function add( a, b ) {
  return a + b;
}, 1 );

// the lockin function will look a bit like this
function lockInFirstArg( fn, a ) {
  // fn = function add
  // a = 1

  // returns a new function which calls fn aka add
  // this function is also a closure, that means it keeps access to the scope of
  // lockInFirstArg so it can still use the variable a, even after it was returned
  return function( b ) {
    return a + b; // inlined add
  };
}
```

So in the end he `var add1 =` assigment is equal to:

```
//  is equal to this
var add1 = function( b ) {
    return 1 + b;
};
```

What comes into play here is that functions are both first class objects and [closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work), no magic just plain JavaScript :)

Comment: Ohhhhhhhh. It took me a minute, but I see now. Thanks a billion, I don't think I could have gone to sleep without understanding this :)

Answer (score 2):

The point of this code is that `b` is the parameter of a new function produced by calling `lockInFirstArg`.  The intuition is that you call `lockInFirstArg` passing in a function `fn` which takes two arguments and some other value `a`.  It then produces a function which, if given some value (let's call it `b`), applies the function `fn` to `a` and `b`.  This is similar to taking the function `fn`, locking the parameter `a` in place, then returning the resulting function.

By the way, this term is sometimes called "currying."  This has a technical meaning, but it's pretty close to the meaning of this code here.

Comment: I have no doubt your answer is right, but I can't wrap my head around why it works. Would you mind elaborating further, perhaps using an example? The part I specifically get stuck on is how creating A var with no args, then calling it with an arg pushes that arg to b in the func. Maybe I'm missing some magic behind returning functions?